# Querying json using getJSON displays "undefined" instead of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, getjson

I'm trying to use getJSON with jQuery, get the URL of an image and display it on this webpage.

The URL of the API works (shows a json), and the images exist, but "undefined" is displayed instead.

Any ideas?

```html
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#driver").click(function(event){

      $.getJSON("https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?earth_date=2015-6-3&api_key=API_KEY", {data: "value"}, function(json) { 
        $('#stage').html('<img src="' + json.photos.img_src + '">');
        $('#stage').append('<img src="' + json.photos.img_src + '">');
        $('#stage').append('<p> ID: ' + json.photos.id+ '</p>');
      })
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it returns an array and you do not reference an element from the array

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#driver").click(function(event){

      $.getJSON("https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?earth_date=2015-6-3&api_key=cypvw52ysZT16N9HAFuh5bEDXb8lvDmw90ff4v26", {data: "value"}, function(json) { 
        //$('#stage').html('<img src="' + json.photos[0].img_src + '">');
        $('#stage').append('<img src="' + json.photos[0].img_src + '">');
        $('#stage').append('<p> ID: ' + json.photos[0].id+ '</p>');
      })
    });
  });



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stage"></div>
<button id="driver">test</button>
```

Comment: 429 = Too Many Requests ... oops!

Comment: maybe that's why the snippet in the question wasn't made runnable, to avoid too many requests being made against the OP's api key

Comment: `we killed` - no, he killed it